# Laying out widgets from the corners and grow one with window

Tags: dart, layout

I’d like to place

- an unspecified number of Text widgets from top-left to bottom
- 3 TextButton widgets from bottom-right to left and
- a random parent content widget top-right

The Text and TextButton widgets should only take their minimum space while the the content widget should expand to bottom-left (upon windows resizing) with its children centered like [so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xCLu.png).

Maybe I’m just unlucky or misled/spoiled by Qt’s QSpacerItem…?
This is a desktop App so “windows resizing” really makes sense in flutter context! ;)

Also, more generally, is there a way to directly nest (some kind of) Row/Column instances and stretch Widgets down/right?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a combination of `Row`, `Column` and `Expanded` to achieve this effect.

I'm going to assume that the bottom left corner belongs to the left-hand side bar. With that in mind, your basic structure can look something like this:

```
Row(
  children: [
    // Side bar
    SizedBox(
      width: 250,
      ListView.builder(
        // Display text widgets
      ),
    ),
    // This widget will fill whatever space remains in the Row after the side bar
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // This widget will fill all the space before the footer
          const Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Resizable Window"),
            ),
          ),
          // Footer with buttons
          SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                // Your buttons
              ]
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

[Full example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=cc6ec62d20090d09b972b8c1f48909b1)

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped instantly. Maybe I'll implement the HBoxLayout, VBoxLayout and SpacerItem myself in the future for easier handling. But for now I have something to work with!

Comment: Glad to hear it :)